# Laravel 5.5 Axios POST results in 419 error

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, axios, laravel-5.5

I am trying to make a POST-request to my Laravel API from Vue. The `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header is set correctly (I see this in the POST-package sent to the server).

The route has the default `web`-middleware.

**Request**

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:api.xxx.local
Origin:http://manager.xxx.local
Referer:http://manager.xxx.local/location/planning/2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN:EAf94SFJWBhlcwzxrq7nyygrnRSmZTavrnKYHv5C
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response**

```
Request URL:http://api.xxx.local/locationplanning/deleteentry/15
Request Method:POST
Status Code:419 unknown status
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Error Stack:**

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 203,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 175,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 47,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 59,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/app/Http/Middleware/ForgetDomainParameter.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\forgetDomainParameter",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 647,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 622,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 588,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 577,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kitchenradar/server/public/index.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: better to check your laravel.log file, you will get clear error message.

Comment: @ankitpatel, log is empty but I get this logtrace (see edit)

Comment: Can you make sure your route is working? Maybe you can try it using postman. @rakete

Comment: If I change the method to GET (in routes and axios) there is no error anymore...

Comment: Try deactivating csrf middleware in kernel

Comment: It works if I deactivate it but I need the Auth.... Auth::user() is null when I deactivate it..

Comment: You now have your issue sorted out, check again the procedure listed [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: It read this procedure several times.. And the header is set.. but it doesn't help.. Does the X-CSRF token in the header "replaces" the POST-parameter?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the page that has the form?

Comment: There is no form.. we are talking about vue2

Comment: Whatever you are using to make the request

Comment: There is no form when making API requests with axios...

Comment: Yes I was asking you to post your request, but anyway, I think you should disable CSRF security for API requests, and enable Laravel Passport

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that we're sending the request from one domain to another. The web frontend domain is *manager.xxx.local* while the API domain is *api.xxx.local*.

This is important because cookies are constrained to the domain they originate from. For security, *the browser will not send cookies to a different domain* by default. Laravel stores the CSRF token in the user's session for web requests and *sends a session cookie* to the browser to maintain this session.

Even though the [*bootstrap.js* file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js#L32), which ships with a default Laravel project, adds the CSRF token header for AJAX requests through axios, we still need a session so that Laravel can compare the token header to the value on the server.

We see the 419 HTTP status code—usually the result of a `TokenMismatchException`—because the API request is not associated with a user session (no session cookie), so *no CSRF token state exists in the session*. Because of this, Laravel considers the token invalid for the API request.

We can solve this problem a couple of different ways. Modern browsers support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (CORS) which, in part, allows us to share cookies between domains via AJAX. Our server needs to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Read [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more information. The [Laravel CORS](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package by Barry vd. Heuvel can help set this up if we don't want to manually configure our application or webserver.

Then, we can configure AJAX requests to forward cookies to a different domain by setting the following property on the `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

In axios, we can [configure `withCredentials` per request](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```
axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
```

...or set it as the default:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

If we're using Vue Resource, we can set a similar configuration option:

```
Vue.http.options.credentials = true;
```

Even when we fix these issues, the current design relies on server-side sessions to maintain state for the CSRF token validation. Conventional APIs are typically *stateless* (no server-side session tied to a user) and authenticate requests using some form of access token (OAuth, JWT, etc.). Note that the CSRF token is *not* one such token.

For a more robust API framework, consider using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/passport). We can add the [`CreateFreshApiToken` middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) that automatically generates an encrypted JWT to pass the user ID and CSRF token state so that we can build a sessionless API.

If we don't want to build a full API, such as if our AJAX requests just supplement the views generated by the server, we may not want to complicate the application by using a separate domain for these requests.

**Notes:**

> It works if I deactivate it but I need the Auth.... Auth::user() is null when I deactivate it.

The user is `null` *not* because we deactivated CSRF, but because we don't have a session to begin with (the session cookie wasn't sent to the API domain).

> If I change the method to GET (in routes and axios) there is no error anymore

Laravel does not check the CSRF token for requests that semantically *read* data (GET, HEAD, and OPTIONS). It verifies the token only for requests that *modify* data (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.).

*Side note*: this is important to remember because an attacker can forge a GET request that modifies a user's data if we don't set up our routes appropriately. Developers commonly make the mistake of using a link (often with `.btn`) to make a simple request like deleting a record:

```
<a href="/posts/delete/{id}">Delete Post</a>
```

A malicious site can place the same link on a page and the request will bypass CSRF protection when clicked because the browser sends a GET request for the link.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see what's going on without checking many places in the project, so I'll list some possible causes, and hope that it'll point you in the correct direction

First probable cause, the 419 http code is trigerred by some condition in your source code. This is higly unprobable given the callstack, but the error may be catched by some middleware and recreated (so wrong call stack).

Another probable cause, the CSRF protection. Given that it works for GET and not for POST (see comments), it's highly probable that the CSRF protection is triggered and refuse the request. To correct that, simply disable the CSRF middleware by using the `api`(instead of `web`) middleware OR adding the route into VerifyCsrfToken class. See [How to disable some routes for CSRF validation](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes)

CSRF protection isn't needed for API routes, these are needed only for POST forms on "standard" webpages.

Comment: I tried to use the api middleware and the web middleware. My problem is I need the Auth::user() in the controller to check the permissions for several actions. I don't think, that Passport is a good solution because the user is logged in through normal blade views/controller. Its not a SPA, I am just using Vue2 to improve the usability and fetching some data in my blade-views. But how to get the authenticated user? Tried to duplicate the default web-middleware, removed VerifyCsrfToken and added auth-middleware but then I always get forwarded to the login page...

Comment: I debugged now into the VerfiyCsrfToken middleware and found out, that the $request->session()->token() is regenerated on every new POST request....

Comment: Auth middleware only need the Session middleware, not the CSRF token one. So it should work if you only have Session and Auth in the correct order. Or as specified in my link, you can disable some routes directly in the CSRF middleware without touching the kernel config at all!