# When I make Axios POST i got 419 (unknown status) Error 0

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

When i make Axios.get it work properly but Axios.post not working and i got 419 error. please help me sir i am totally beginner in laravel and react

```
axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Header-Top`, headerTop )
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res.data);
})


Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function() {
Route::resource('api/Header-Top', 'HeaderTopController');
});
```

Comment: Did you configured the CSRF Token?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response sir, yes sir  i add <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">  in welcome.blade.php

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444426/laravel-5-5-axios-post-results-in-419-error

Comment: Thank you so much@FelippeDuarte Sir for solving my problem.  According to you link i Add protected $except = [
        //
        'api/Header-Top'
    ];   and problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're missing your CSRF token from your request.
You have 2 options to fix it in Laravel and ReactJS.

**1)** You will need to include it using:

```
Axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token_var;
```

**2)** **OR** go to `/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` (NOT RECOMMENDED for most cases like forms, etc)

and add the URL you're using under $except = []

like this:

```
protected $except = [
'/route-url-example'
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mostafa Mohsen Sir for solving my problem.  According to you 2 option i Add protected $except = [
        //
        'api/Header-Top'
    ];   and problem solved

Comment: Where do you put `Axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token_var;` ?