# Laravel React 419 on POST request while XCSRF is in the header

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post

As described above I recieve a 419 everytime I try to post to a controller..

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback((_event) => {

    window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
    };

    console.log(document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'));

    axios.post('/bol/accounts/create', {
        bol_public_key: '12345454',
        bol_private_key: '123454'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

The token is in the request header so it should be fine?

```
:authority: *.ngrok.io
:method: POST
:path: /accounts/create
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 86
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: https://8be933f3b3a6.ngrok.io
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://*.ngrok.io/?hmac=564b7bb3c74e59e7a578e50f3bbfb318dfc3d7dea58820d9d66b46ade87b6659&locale=en-NL&new_design_language=true&session=d39033c75fb0a751a23596feae7cb86f704114e33b2bd1c676ddd1bea05ab759&shop=*.myshopify.com&timestamp=1607901296
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token: tUQk4qMxSNIvTx07oePArv94CEk2LedNmadu2Ozs
```

Comment: This is a CORS issue. Which domains are your front and back end apps on?

Comment: The back-end is just on my localhost but it's connected with Shopify APP (https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify)

Comment: Take a really good look here and update your question if you have any further issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444426/laravel-5-5-axios-post-results-in-419-error

Comment: I tried to adding it both ways but still seems to keep failing :( `window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

        console.log(document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'));

        axios.post('/bol/accounts/create', {
            withCredentials: true,
            bol_public_key: '12345454',
            bol_private_key: '123454'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });` pastebin: https://pastebin.com/JW9Wpqaf